# Most recently visited buffer appears at bottom of buffer-list

Tags: buffers, buffer-list

I have a function key bound to the command `buffer-menu-other-window`. But sometimes when I hit that key, while I am editing file `foo.py`, file `foo.py` appears at the bottom of my buffer list instead of the top, which is a real pain.

[The same thing happens when I type `C-x C-b`, which is bound to command `list-buffers`. As far as I can see, `buffer-menu-other-window` is an old name for `list-buffers`.]

This problem appears (apparently) randomly, and then does not go away until I quit emacs and restart it. So I assume I have accidentally set something. But is there a way to fix this without quitting and restarting emacs?

Comment: A user cannot entirely control the order in which buffers appear in the global buffer-list or the frame-local buffer-list.  Consider keeping a separate list and organize it in the manner desired, refreshing it as needed and removing buffers that are dead.  Alternatively, consider a different method of organization such as alphabetical, or alphabetical plus additional criteria such as major-mode.  To have an idea how to organize buffers using a separately maintained list, Alp Aker has a library called `frame-buffs` and the custom list is imbeded as a frame parameter; i.e., frame-local lists.

Comment: I switched to `ibuffer` and never looked back. See e.g. https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20187/organize-the-buffer-list

Comment: @NickD ibuffer is certainly preferable. If you give that as an answer I will mark is as best (unless someone else answer very soon, which doesn't look like happening).

Comment: Update: `ibuffer` occasionally stops working for no apparent reason, i.e. it stops updating; which is even more annoying than the problem I originally asked about! So after 3 months trying it, I'm going back to `buffer-menu` / `buffer-menu-other-window`